# Paginação WordPress

Tags: wordpress, paginação

Bom dia, galera!

Estou com um problema algum tempo para fazer uma paginação com wordpress.

Estou tentando implementar uma paginação estilizada, porém estou com uma certa dificuldade para fazer funcionar de certa forma.

```
function wp_pagination( $query=null, $wpcpn_posts=null )
{

    $big = 999999999;

    $published_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;
    $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
    $page_number_max = ceil($published_posts / $posts_per_page);


    $paginate = paginate_links(
        array(
            'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'type'      => 'array',
            'total'     => $page_number_max,
            'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
            'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
        )
    );
    if ( $page_number_max > 1 && $paginate ) {
        echo '
        <nav aria-label="Navegação da página" id="paginacao">
                            <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        ';
        foreach ( $paginate as $page ) {                        
            echo '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link rounded-circle" href="'. $page .'">'. $page .'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '
            </ul>
        </nav>
        ';
    }}



                        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );
                        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ 



                        <div class="card rounded" id="post-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <a href="<?= get_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>" class="col-12 col-sm-6"><img  src="<?= get_the_post_thumbnail_url($recent["ID"], 'full'); ?>" class="card-img-top" height="232" alt="Imagem de capa do card"></a>
                                <div class="card-body col-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <p><span><?= (get_the_category()[0]->name); ?></span></p>
                                    <a href="<?= get_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>"><h5 class="card-title"><?= $recent['post_title']; ?></h5></a>
                                    <!-- Lembrar que a descrição do blog deve terno maximo 153 char-->
                                    <p class="card-text"><?= limitar_caracteres($recent['post_excerpt'], 153); ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?= get_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>" class="card-text verMais">Ver mais</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

O resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me dá um help, por favor :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite Moises!

Há alguns dias escrevi algo em https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/357161/problem-with-pagination-link-error-404/357197#357197

Mas basicamente é isso aqui:
Na listagem seu template...

```
<?php
$actual_page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'seu_post_type_aqui',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $actual_page
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php wp_pagination($query->max_num_pages);?>
```

Em seu arquivo functions.php :

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('wp_pagination') ): 
    function wp_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {
        $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;

        global $actual_page;
        if(empty($actual_page)) $actual_page = 1;

        if($pages == '') {
            global $wp_query;
            $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$pages)
            {
                $pages = 1;
            }
        }

        if(1 != $pages) {
            echo '<ul class="pagination">';
            if($actual_page > 2 && $actual_page > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link(1)) . '"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></span></a></li>';
            if($actual_page > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($actual_page - 1)) . '"><span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span></a></li>';

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
                if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $actual_page + $range + 1 || $i <= $actual_page - $range - 1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                    echo ($actual_page == $i)? '<li class="active"><a href="#">' . esc_html($i) . '</a></li>' : '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)) . '">' . esc_html($i) . '</a></li>';
                }
            }

            if ($actual_page < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($actual_page + 1)) . '" class="next"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a></li>';
            if ($actual_page < $pages - 1 &&  $actual_page + $range - 1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($pages)) . '"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span></a></li>';
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado Daniel!